# Can you load a local html resource into a WebView?

Tags: android, webview

Can I design a html file, store it in the resources and call it up with the `WebView`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You absolute can, you just need to create a folder in an assets directory on the root of your project and you can have the browser load a url like this...

```
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/UI/mylocalhtmlfile.htm");
```

Where UI in the above path is a folder under the assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

positive. You can turn android into a mini web-server which means you can make a call like this: localhost:1234/example.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'd like to use AJaX patterns on a WebView in an Android app… Any pointers much appreciated!